# Numbering align-environments

Tags: sectioning, numbering, align

I'm writing in the `article` class. The `align`-environments are being numbered continuously, but I want them to be numbered like "section.number in this section". How can I do that? :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `\counterwithin{equation}{section}`, with `\usepackage{chngcntr}` Generally, we prefer a minimal working code ;-)

Comment: The `amsmath` package provides `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`.

Comment: Thank you! I just needed this too, so I upvote, but as I am already using `amsmath`, I will go with `\numberwithin`. I already have too many packages and no time to think which ones are not needed :-)

Answer (score 5):

Either use `\numberwithin{equation}{section}` from `amsmath` or `mathtools` or the `chngcntr` package (if more than this is needed, e.g. `\counterwithout` or the starred versions `\counterwithin*` etc.)

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chngcntr}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\counterwithin{equation}{section}


\begin{document}
\section{A section}
\begin{align}
  E &= mc^{2} \\
  E^2 &= p^{2}c^{2} + m^{2}c^{4}
\end{align}


\section{Another section}

\begin{align}
  E &= mc^{2} \\
  E^2 &= p^{2}c^{2} + m^{2}c^{4}
\end{align}

\counterwithout{equation}{section} % Remove the resetting by `section`

\section{Yet another section}

\begin{align}
  E &= mc^{2} \\
  E^2 &= p^{2}c^{2} + m^{2}c^{4}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `chngcntr` is not necessary as `amsmath` already provides `\numberwithin`.

Comment: @egreg: No, but there might be situations where `\counterwithin*` etc. or `\counterwithout` might be necessary.